# Deleted data still prompts as existed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I have 2 process for sending a data. 1st is from a table and 2nd is by textboxes. "table_select" is where I retrieve the data, and "attendee_table" is where I send the data temporarily before I save the process. On submit, it saves to database.

The problem is when I check for duplicate entries, it functions well. But when I delete one of the entries, it is still prompting that the entry is existed. **NOTE: It is not yet saved in the database.**

But when I save it to database, the removed entry is not included in the database. What does this mean?

Here is my Jquery/Javascript code:

```
attendees_id=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
```

// ADD ATTENDEES BY SEARCH

```
    var addMem = [];
    $("#add_button").click(function(){


        $('#table_select input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){

            var getRow = $(this).parents('tr');
            var value = (getRow.find('td:eq(2)').html()); //names
            var value1 = (getRow.find('td:eq(3)').html()); //specialty
            var value3 = (getRow.find('td:eq(1)').html()); //prc

             var index = $.inArray(value3, addMem);

        if (index >= 0){
                        alert('exists');
                        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).uniform('refresh');
        }

        else {
            $('#attendee_table tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prc[' + attendees_id + ']" id="prc" value="' + value3 + '" readonly></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + value + '" id="names" name="name[' + attendees_id + ']" readonly></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + value1 + '" id="specialties" name="specialty[' + attendees_id + ']" readonly></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="delete_btn1[' + attendees_id + ']" id="delete_btn1" onclick="deleteMem(this)" value="Delete"></td></tr>');

            addMem.push(value3,value,value1);

            $("#mod_search").modal('hide');
            attendees_id=attendees_id+1;
        }

        });


    });
```

// ADD ATTENDEES BY ADD

```
    var addNon = [];
$("#addRow").click(function (e) {

    var val2 = $("#id_no").val();
    var val = $("#attendee_name").val();
    var val1 = $("#specialty").val();

    var ind = $.inArray(val, addNon);

    if (val == ""){

        alert('Enter name of attendee.')
    }

    else if (val1 == ""){

        alert('Enter specialty of attendee.')
    }

    else{
            if (ind >= 0){
                        alert('exists');
                        $('#attendee_name').val('');
                        $('#specialty').val('');

        }
        else {

        $('#attendee_table tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="prc[' + attendees_id + ']" id="prc" value=""></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + val + '" id="names" name="name['+ attendees_id +']" readonly></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + val1 +'" id="specialties" name="specialty[' + attendees_id + ']" readonly></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="delete_btn[' + attendees_id + ']" id="delete_btn" value="Delete" onclick="deleteNon(this)" ></td></tr>');

            addNon.push(val,val1);


        $('#attendee_name').val('');
        $('#specialty').val('');
            }
    }
    attendees_id=attendees_id+1;
});
});
```

//DELETE DATA FROM SEARCH

```
function deleteMem(t){

var row = t.parentNode.parentNode;

var yes = confirm('Are you sure?');



    if (yes){
        document.getElementById("attendee_table").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        console.log(row);

    }
    else{
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

//DELETE DATA FROM ADD

```
function deleteNon(t){

var row = t.parentNode.parentNode;

var yes = confirm('Are you sure?');

    if (yes){
         document.getElementById("attendee_table").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
            console.log(row);

    }
    else{
            event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This is my "table_select":

```
<table class="table table-hover table-managed" id="table_select">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>PRC</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Speciality</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $sql_search="SELECT * FROM `personal_profile`";
            $sql_run=mysql_query($sql_search);
            while($m=mysql_fetch_array($sql_run))
            {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="member_select[]" id="member_select" value="<?php @$m['id'];  ?>"></td>
            <td><?php echo @$m['prc_license_num']; ?></td>
            <td id="names"><?php echo @$m['lastname'].', '.@$m['firstname'].' '.@$m['middlename'];?></td>
            <td id="specialties"><?php echo @$m['speciality'];?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

"attendee_table":

```
<table class="table table-managed table-hover" id="attendee_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>PRC</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Speciality</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $sql_select="SELECT * FROM `event_attendees` WHERE `id`='".@$_REQUEST['member_select']."'";
            $sql_run=mysql_query($sql_select);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_run))
        {

        ?>
        <tr>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
    <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

//ADDING ATTENDEE BY TEXTBOX

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attendee_name" name="attendee_name" value="<?=@$_REQUEST['name']?>"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod_search" id="search_btn" name="search_btn" style="visibility:hidden;" >Search</button>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <label class="control-label">Specialty/Profession</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="specialty" id="specialty" value="<?=@$_REQUEST['speciality']?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addRow" name="addRow" style="visibility:hidden;">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where/what did I missed? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a more code please? This isn't enough. And yes, this is a quick response.

Comment: In what part of my code you want a further look?

Comment: I've jut included the adding data by textbox.